# variance bound for strictly log-concave random variables

Tags: real-analysis, probability-theory, convex-analysis

Let $f:\mathbb{R}^p \to \mathbb{R}$ be a measurable function such that the integral $\int_{\mathbb{R}^p} \exp\{-f(\theta)\}\,d\theta$ is finite and define the probability density $\pi(\theta)$ as $$\pi(\theta) = \frac{\exp\{-f(\theta)\}}{\int_{\mathbb{R}^p} \exp\{-f(u)\}\, du}$$ and its mean value as $\bar{\theta} = \int_{\mathbb{R}^p} \theta\,\pi(\theta)\,d\theta$. Assume that $f$ is $m$-strongly convex in the sense that $$f(\theta) - f(\theta') - \nabla f(\theta')\cdot (\theta - \theta') \geq \frac{m}{2}\,\|\theta - \theta'\|^2_2$$ for all $\theta,\,\theta' \in \mathbb{R}^p$. I found in a paper that we have $$\int_{\mathbb{R}^p} \|\bar{\theta} - \theta\|^2_2\,\pi(\theta)\,d\theta \leq \frac{p}{m}.$$ I have no clue as to why such inequality holds and appreciate any reference or help!